# How to do a micro-benchmark in node.js / unit test code

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm writing some unit tests using mocha and want to do a micro benchmark around a piece of code

Something like this

```
const startTime = getTime();
doOperations();
const endTime = getTime();
console.log(startTime - endTime);
```

is this possible in Javascript / nodejs / mocha?

I'd like to run this in my test environment just to check speed of some critical operations on nodejs server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### For browser

Use [`performance.measure()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/measure) API

##### For Node.js

Use similar [`performance.measure`](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#performancemeasurename-startmarkoroptions-endmark) API

For just console logging , you could use [`console.time`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/time) API alongwith [`console.timeLog`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/timeLog) and [`console.timeEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/timeEnd)